# XCode 9.1 / iOS 11.1 : app icon is missing when application is run on device

Tags: ios, xcode

After I upgraded to XCode 9.1 and iOS 11.1, when I run an application (install from XCode to device), the app icon is missing on the device (tested iPhone 7 so far). 
When I install the app via Testflight or as an ad-hoc distribution, the icon is present, as well as in the simulator.
In the asset catalogue all icons are present and it worked until the last update to 11.1

Did anybody else experience this and knows already how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to clean project folder or delete derived data?

Comment: For me: iPhone 7 & iOS 11.1.1 & Xcode 9.1 = icon present

Comment: @kirander: Yes, i did: clean project, clean build folder, deleted derived data with no success

Comment: @Wasserfloh we are facing the same issue. Did you able to find out anything causing it?

Comment: @susim unfortunately I did not.  I noticed in some projects it's working, in others it isn't. What the difference is, I still can't tell.